# How to import code from other projects to next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js, discord.js, node-modules, zlib

So im making a discord dashboard using next.js and discord.js, and finally the moment to use the client came, but im encountering several errors to import it, here is the structure of my project:

[image]

so as u can see, i have a folder named welfare with 2 different projects: poenixts (the discord bot) and welfare-web (the next.js dashboard), so basically in the file im requiring the client, i imported it as normal:

```
//welfare-web in GuildsContent.tsx
import { client } from "../../../../../phoenixts/Classes/Client/Client";
```

but when doing that, in the build i get an error related to zlib-sync:

```
Failed to compile.

../phoenixts/node_modules/zlib-sync/build/Release/zlib_sync.node
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '⌂' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

i tried installing zlib-sync in both projects, adding zlib-sync to transpilePackages in next.config.js but nothing works.

Comment: this is some webpack error, I don't know zlib. But how are you compiling/running this? I'd consider exporting the client as a package and having the dashboard import/install it properly like that, not just grabbing a single file

Comment: im compiling this using next build && next start, and i get it, make it a package so i can import it in my bot and in my web, right?

Comment: not sure what the bot is, but I mean if you could do something `import { client } from 'phoenixts'` something like that where `phoenixts` is your homemade package

Comment: are you not using `npm run dev` when developing? does that work? (or `next dev`)

Comment: i’ll try to figure it out and make it a package bc the client basically it’s a class with a lot of handlers, but yeah i’m not using next dev bc sometimes next doesn’t compiles all of my api routes, idk why

Comment: I'd seriously recommend figuring that out, next dev has better error messages than the built site

Comment: well i did it and it did not work at all, i guess ima implement an api for my bot and directly make requests from next